# IN statement error in SQL triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a trigger that insert value to a another table based on a condition,
in my condition thare is an IN statement within IF condition when im trying to insert multiple values using "INSERT INTO SELECT FROM"
it returns following error 
*"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when..."*

here is my code

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[WentOut] ON  [dbo].[TB_EVENT_LOG]
       AFTER INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @AID int

        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        IF ((SELECT  nTNAEvent from inserted) IN(1,2,3))    
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO Cen.WentOutLog  (AutoID, nUserID, nOutDateTime,nOutTNAEvent ,nReaderID) select nEventLogIdn,nUserID, nDateTime,nTNAEvent, nReaderIdn from inserted 

        END
END
```

it works for single value but not for multiple value inserting  "INSERT INTO SELECT FROM"
thanks in advance

Comment: triggers must be BATCH aware.....Search SO for many examples...

Comment: @mitch can give me an example, i tried everywhere couldn't understood those examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Mitch `trigger` doesn't fire for each row. If am not wrong this is what you need.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[WentOut]
ON [dbo].[TB_EVENT_LOG]
AFTER INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @AID INT

      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      IF EXISTS(SELECT nTNAEvent
                FROM   inserted
                WHERE  nTNAEvent IN ( 1, 2, 3 ))
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Cen.WentOutLog
                        (AutoID,nUserID,nOutDateTime,nOutTNAEvent,
                         nReaderID)
            SELECT nEventLogIdn,nUserID,nDateTime,nTNAEvent,
                   nReaderIdn
            FROM   inserted
            WHERE  nTNAEvent IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
        END
      IF EXISTS(SELECT nTNAEvent
                FROM   inserted
                WHERE  nTNAEvent IN ( 0 ))
        BEGIN
        --statement
        END
  END
```

Comment: if im add an else-if condition it will not work according to above condition right?

Comment: @ThilankaIshara not it will work you can add else if condition

Comment: i want something like this 
IF EXISTS(SELECT nTNAEvent   FROM   inserted  WHERE  nTNAEvent IN ( 1, 2, 3 ))
begin
....
end
else if EXISTS(SELECT nTNAEvent   FROM   inserted  WHERE  nTNAEvent IN ( 0 ))
begin
...
end


it wouldn't worked

Comment: but according to your example it only return true in fist if, so it doesn't go to else if

Comment: no its not, thare are records for nEventIdn are 1,2,3,4,0 .. so it always goes to first IF condiotion

Comment: @ThilankaIshara sorry remove else. check now